# Custom Table Coding for Table Cells

Tags: tables

Below is my code

Normal Table:

```
\documentclass{article}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{Sample Table.\label{tab:active_distance}}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{lcccc}
\hline
H1 & H2 & H3& H4 & H5\\
\hline
Cell 1&Cell 2& Cell 3& Cell 4&Cell 5\\
Cell 1&Cell 2& Cell 3& Cell 4&Cell 5\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

and i need to use my custom tags like the one mentioned below for conversion and re use purposes,
Customized Table :

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\caption{Sample Table.\label{tab:active_distance}}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{lcccc}
\hline
\thead{
\tr{\td{H1}\td{H2}\td{H3}\td{H4}\td{H5}}}
\hline
\tbody{
\tr{\td{Cell 1}\td{Cell 2}\td{Cell 3}\td{Cell 4}\td{Cell 5}}}
\tr{\td{Cell 1}\td{Cell 2}\td{Cell 3}\td{Cell 4}\td{Cell 5}}}
 }
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Is it possible to define the below to create a table, please guide

```
\thead{} - Table Head
 \tbody{} - Table Body
 \tr{} - Table row
 \td{} - Table Cell
```

Is this Possible, Thanks in Advance,

Answer (score 1):

An implementation with `expl3`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentEnvironment{itabular}{O{c}m}% 'implicit' tabular
 {% 1. change the meaning of \thead, \tbody, \tr and \td
  % actually \thead and \tbody are the same, while \tr and \td are just markers
  \cs_set_eq:NN \thead \itabular_tbody:n
  \cs_set_eq:NN \tbody \itabular_tbody:n
  % 2. make the tabular
  \begin{tabular}[#1]{#2}
 }
 {
  \end{tabular}
 }

\tl_new:N \l_itabular_body_tl
\seq_new:N \l_itabular_rows_seq
\seq_new:N \l_itabular_one_row_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \itabular_tbody:n
 {
  \tl_clear:N \l_itabular_body_tl
  % divide at \tr, the first item is empty and discarded
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_itabular_rows_seq { \tr } { #1 }
  \seq_pop_left:NN \l_itabular_rows_seq \l_tmpa_tl
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_itabular_rows_seq
   {
    % divide at \td, the first item is empty and discarded
    \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_itabular_one_row_seq { \td } { ##1 }
    \seq_pop_left:NN \l_itabular_one_row_seq \l_tmpa_tl
    % fill in the body, items are separated by &, add \\ at the end
    \tl_put_right:Nx \l_itabular_body_tl
     {
      \seq_use:Nn \l_itabular_one_row_seq { & }
      \exp_not:N \\
     }
   }
  % deliver the body
  \tl_use:N \l_itabular_body_tl
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{lcccc}
\hline
H1 & H2 & H3& H4 & H5\\
\hline
Cell 1&Cell 2& Cell 3& Cell 4&Cell 5\\
Cell 1&Cell 2& Cell 3& Cell 4&Cell 5\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\begin{itabular}{lcccc}
\hline
\thead{
  \tr{\td{H1}\td{H2}\td{H3}\td{H4}\td{H5}}
}
\hline
\tbody{
  \tr{\td{Cell 1}\td{Cell 2}\td{Cell 3}\td{Cell 4}\td{Cell 5}}
  \tr{\td{Cell 1}\td{Cell 2}\td{Cell 3}\td{Cell 4}\td{Cell 5}}
}
\hline
\end{itabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]